# Maven transitive dependency old version

Tags: maven

there is a dependency in `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I have upgraded from 3.0.0 to 3.0.6. When I run `mvn dependency:tree` I see the result:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.0.0:compile
```

Hoewer in mvn repository the deppendencies section says:
[image]

So all transitive artifacts' versions are wrong, why it happens? Why mvn did not take latest versions of transitive dependencies?

Comment: Have you defined the version for the spring-boot-starter-security dep manually instead of using parent or BOM spring boot? Currently it looks like that...

Comment: I always define it manually, what is parent and BOM?

Comment: If you define all your transitive dependenciy manually you are doing a lot of uneccessary work... https://maven.apache.org/pom.html (parent pom) .. also check https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html (bom)...